How do I amend Excel plot axis labels (text) with partial, character subscripts?

I have plots where the axis labels are {50m(w)...300m(w)}, such that the 'w' must be a subscript.
If I used the 'Font' option in Excel when formatting the axes, it allows you to check 'subscript', but idiotically makes the entire axis's labels subscript. This means '50mw' entirely becomes a subscript, when I only want this to be 'w'. I have also tried typing subscripts correctly in cells, then selecting data, editing the axis labels by highlighting the correctly subscripted versions in the cells. The axis does not transfer the properties of the cells' subscripts into the labels, and instead, you'd get '50mw', etc, as written. This is a method that works for the legends. But not the axis labels. I haven't been able to find any solutions online
